# Using Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ to estimate $\sin(\frac{\pi}{36})$ to $5$dp

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I was wondering how I could use the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ to estimate $\sin(\frac{\pi}{36})$ to $5$dp?

I know the answer should be $0.08716$ to $5$dp, I tried to do this but using the first to terms of the expansion for $\sin(x)$ below:
$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}= \frac{\pi}{36}-\frac{\pi^3}{36^3 *3!}$$

Which I got to be $0.08716$ this seems right but according to my mark scheme, I should've done:

$$|\frac{x^7}{7!}|=\frac{|x^7|}{5040}$$

"which for $|x|\lt 0.3$ gives a bound of $4.3×10^{−8}$ on the error. Since we have $\frac{π}{36} =0.0872...$
we can therefore use $T_5$ to get the estimate"

I really don't understand why they used $T_5$ and what $x^7$ has to do with it?

If anyone can shed some light on this I would be very greatful!

Comment: Are you familiar with the lagrange error bound?

Comment: You have to use the remainder term to get a bound on the error.  You may indeed get a close estimate with fewer terms, but you have to *prove* it's close.

Comment: How do I use that @Brian

Comment: How do I prove that through because $7!$ is only 4 DP

Comment: @saulspatz see comment above

Comment: Why do you say four decimal places?  ${.3^7\over7!}=4.33928571\cdot10^{-}8$

Comment: @saulspatz oh I see, that gives my 5dp, but then why don’t we use all the terms including $x^7$ instead of just up to it to estimate at the end?

Comment: The $n$th Lagrange remainder gives a bound on the error if all terms from the $n$th on are omitted.  Also in this case, since you only want an answer to $5$ decimal places, it would be pointless to include a term on the order of $10^{-8}$